# xsl param default string cannot start with period

Tags: xml, xslt, param

In my stylesheet I try to set the default value for an input parameter to a string beginning with the dot character. And always receive an error code 0x8004005 - Expected toden 'eof' found 'NAME'.  For example:

```
<xsl:param name="p1" select=".exe"/>
```

However it doesn't matter what follows the dot. Always same error.
How do I form this string to include the first dot?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and easy solution. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You need to specify the "default value" as a string literal**.

Simply change:

```
<xsl:param name="p1" select=".exe"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:param name="p1" select="'.exe'"/>
```

In the former case the value of the `select` attribute is evaluated as an XPath expression -- not as a string.

Comment: @Skippy-VonDrake: Glad my answer was useful. Here at SO the accepted form of gratitude is to accept an answer (by clicking the check-mark next to it). :)

Comment: OK. Next time I'll also learn how to post my questions so that the code is visible! Thanks again.

Comment: @Skippy-VonDrake: I edited this for you. Just select the code, then click on the code button (`{}`).